# How to get place details from google api using place ID in angular 2

Tags: angular, google-places

Goal: Get an JSON with place details data from google. 
Problem: I have 404 Not found Err
Thounght: I think that i created a bad path

This code represents the service and I expect to load the data in my template component.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { CoordinateModel } from "../models/coordinate.model";
import { PlaceCondensedModel } from "../models/place-condensed.model";

import { ConfigService } from "./config.service";

@Injectable()
export class PlacesService {

    constructor(private _http: Http,
        private _config: ConfigService) { }

    list(coordinate: CoordinateModel) {
        const path = this._config.apiUrl + '/places?query=sport&coordinate={latitude},{longitude}'
            .replace('{latitude}', coordinate.lat)
            .replace('{longitude}', coordinate.lng);

        return this._http
            .get(path, { headers: this._config.apiHeaders.Default })
            .map((res: Response) => {
                return res.json();
            });
    }


    getDetails(id: string){
        const path = this._config.apiUrl + '/place/details/json?placeid={id}'
            .replace('{id}', id);

        return this._http
            .get(path, { headers: this._config.apiHeaders.Default })
            .map((res: Response) => {
                return res.json();
            });
    }
}
```

I would like to add that the list() method works and it helped me to write getDetails() using the guidlines from:

> https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Comment: Path should look like https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key="Your-key-from-googleconsole"
Get address from console.log(path) in getdetails funtion and call that from browser